# What is exactly "dran Schuld"?

Tags: difference

I told my German girlfriend the other day that I slept badly, and she told me:

```
War ich dran Schuld? (not sure if Schuld takes here a big "S")
```

Now, I get the idea of what she is trying to say. But I thought the normal way of saying it would be:

```
War es meine Schuld?
```

or

```
War ich schuldig?
```

The way she formulated is quite mysterious. I know *dran* is short for *daran*, but even with that substitution I find weird. It is kinda like hearing in English

```
Was I at it guilt?
```

Usually after the "to be" verb should come an adjective, as in "I am tall" or "I am clever". But what I hear is "I am guilt".

Can someone please explain what is this formulation about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it after having some of your clarifications, you understand how you get from the expression „an etw. schuld sein“ to the question „War ich dran Schuld?“, but are uncomfortable with „an etw. schuld sein“. That confusion is understandable, because it is the same confusion that makes native speakers unsure whether to capitalise „schuld“. The word is not the [noun „Schuld“](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS18447), but the [adjective „schuld“](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GS18448), which means essentially the same as „schuldig“ but is used in different contexts as Kilian has pointed out.

(And as you can see from the second link, the adjective seems to be derived from the noun, and someone with actual grammar knowledge might be able to clarify that relationship to us.)

Comment: Ah, ok, I now see that this has been clarified in the comments to the 5pike's answer. Well, here it is as a separate one.

Comment: Ok, your post synthetized very well what I wanted to find out. There are 2 adjectives "schuld" und "schuldig", and the use cases are the ones Killian explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The word [dran](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dran) is just a short form/colloquial of [daran](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/daran).

So, she could have said:

> War ich daran schuld?

EDIT:

It does not have any special connotations. `War ich dran schuld?`, `War es meine Schuld?` and `War ich schuldig?` pretty much mean all the same `(Was it my fault? Was I to blame?)`, though `War ich schuldig?` sounds a bit stilted, if used in normal conversation.

As Ingmar mentioned in the comment, you can omit `d(a)ran` and just use:

> War ich schuld?

EDIT 2 (addressing the new info):

In this context, `schuld` is an adjective, so you would translate it to `guilty`. Instead of `schuld`, one could use [schul­dig](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schuldig), like:

> War ich schuldig (daran)?

but it does sound a bit stilted.

Comment: I knew about the dran/daran thing. Sorry if I didnt make it clear. I updated the question.

Comment: "War ich d(a)ran Schuld?" is probably the most colloquial way of putting it. Apart from that, it has no particular connotations. "War ich Schuld (daran)?" would be another way.

Comment: "schuld sein" is written with a lower "s". You are not "the blame", you're just the one to blame. -> "Schuld haben", "schuld sein".

Comment: I wouldn't have though twice about it before the orthography reform. These days, not so sure. I probably should've looked it up.

Comment: So in the context that my girlfriend said it, "schuld" is an adjective or a substantive?

Comment: @Dbugger - It's an adjective in this context.

Comment: Oh! So then "schuld" is an adjective? I haven't found it in any dictionary. Could you give me a reference to look that up?

Comment: @Dbugger - Well, Shuld is a substantive, but in this context, it is used as an adjective. Take a look at the Duden pages, they give examples: [Die Schuld](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schuld) - [shuld](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schuld)

Comment: So I take it that while it is used in this context as adjective, that is not "official german", but sort of "umgangssprache"?

Comment: @Dbugger: No, it's perfectly standard. The difference is that *schuldig* is used in a legal context or one of "official" responsibility. *schuld an etwas sein/haben* just means *to be responsible for something*. Just as the English takes a preposition here, so does the German.

Answer (score 1):

(a) and (b) are near-synonymous. (Example (b) should actually read "War es mein**e** Schuld?", for proper concord.) Both can be said by someone apologizing for a minor or major inconvenience.

(c) sounds far more serious; 'schuldig' usually carries a connotation of establishing legal responsibility, and might be used by a judge when pronouncing a sentence. That's not something your girl says to you on waking up, unless you are very comfortable with each other and quite sarcastical.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. My question is more about the formulation of the sentence. "Daran Schuld sein" sounds kinda like "I am guilt at it" which sounds rather weird. I updated the question explaining it better.

Answer (score 1):

The interchangeable expressions (note the different capitalization)

> [an etwas] schuld sein
> [an etwas] Schuld haben
> [an etwas] die Schuld haben
> [für etwas] verantwortlich sein

mean

> be to blame [for something]

They are particularly useful for mentioning the topic (the “something” in square brackets).

In the given example, the topic is clear and it is simply referred to by „daran“:

> Ich bin [daran] schuld.
>
> I am to blame [for it].

However, if the topic is clear, you can do without the part in square brackets:

> Ich bin schuld.
>
> I am to blame.